# Mapbox setFilter method not working as expected

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I am currently porting an app made with Vue2 to Quasar framework, which is based on Vue3. There is a map made with Mapbox GL 1.6.1 which I have to port using current version which is 3.6.5. It is giving quite a headache as, not only I am a rather new mapbox user, but also a few things have changed since 1.6.1 version, to be more precise my problem is with filters.

The app deals with power plant inspections. Anomalies detected are painted on a map and can be displayed according some criteria, their priority for instance (low, middle or high). When building the layer a geojson is made dinamically with data from the backend, so besides 'type' and 'geometry' also 'properties' is set, containing data which can be used to filter what is shown on the map.

The layer itself as you would expect filters the source by geometry type, when displayed on console there is the first difference I have detected between both mapbox versions. On 1.6.1 the layer has:

```
filter: Array(3)
  0: "=="
  1: "$type"
  2: "Polygon"
  length: 3
  ...
paint: { ... }
source: "source-name"
type: "fill"
```

while on 3.6.5 it has:

```
filter: Proxy
  [[Handler]]: Object
  [[Target]]: Array(3)
    0: "=="
    1: "$type"
    2: "Polygon"
    ...
```

In the older version there is an array, in the new one there is an object, which is not the same. I guess this in itself should not be a problem, as it is mapbox who deals with the data format, but the trouble comes when I try to add a filter to the map. Both versions of the app do it like this:

```
const layer = layer-name
const filter = ['==', 'severity', 3]

this.map.setFilter(layer, filter)  // old app, options api syntax
map.value.setFilter(layer, filter) // new app, composition api syntax
```

Here comes trouble. In the old app after executing the method the filter property of the layer is unchanged, as expected it filters polygon features from the source and only rezzes those with the property 'severity' == 3. But when logging the content of the layer in the new app something is wrong:

```
filter: Proxy
  [[Handler]]: Object
  [[Target]]: Array(3)
    0: "=="
    1: "severity"
    2: "3"
    ...
```

and obviously it hides all polygons. Said in another way, in Mapbox version 1.6.1 the map.setFilter method filters the content of the 'properties' property in the data source, but in 3.6.5 it changes the 'filter' property of the layer instead. I have looked in the mapbox docs and found something on https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-features-within-map-view/ :

```
map.on('movestart', () => {
  // reset features filter as the map starts moving
  map.setFilter('airport', ['has', 'abbrev']);
});
```

and tried something like this:

```
map.value.setFilter(layer-name, ['==', ['get', 'severity'], 3)
```

but it does not work. Also have looked on forums but have not found a problem similar to mine. I am sure there is something I don't get, could anyone please tell how the filtering should be done? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I made a small mistake with Mapbox version, current release is 2.7.0, not 3.6.5.

Comment: Finally I found the reason for that behavior. The data I was trying to filter was a number, but the select field gave the data in string format. it seems that if you set the filter with a data type different than required Mapbox applies the filter not to feature's properties but to the layer itself.